# How to get string in byte array received?

Tags: arrays

I have following data fields:

```
int iData1 = 100;   
int iData2 = 5000;
float fData3 = 80.5f;
float fData4 = 100.1f;
String str1 = "BBBB";
```

Sending data as byte array as below:

```
ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(BUF_SIZE);  
buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
buf.putInt(bData1);
buf.putInt(iData2);
buf.putFloat(fData3);
buf.putFloat(fData4);
buf.put(str1.getBytes());
sendBytes(buf.array());
```

To parse the byte array received, I can get each field a follow:

```
iData1 = bbf.getInt();
iData2 = bbf.getInt();
iData3 = bbf.getInt();
fData3 = bbf.getFloat();
fData4 = bbf.getFloat();
```

But how to get the string data field (str1) in the array received?
Any hint would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the length of the string before the string. Then read the string in two steps:

```
sDataLen = bbf.getInt();
bbf.get(sData5, 0, sDataLen);
```

Comment: Hi Barmar. Would you be more clarify by "Put the length of the string before the string."?

Comment: After calling sData5 = bbf.get(sDataLen); I get a byte, what should I do next?

Comment: See my answer: you then read that many bytes into sData5. That's what `bbf.get(sDataLen)` is assumed to do. I don't know what language you're using, you need to translate that to whatever is appropriate for your language.

Comment: I don't know Java, but I read the ByteBuffer documentation and found this: `bbf.get(sData5, 0, sDataLen);`.